# In mac OS, Is it possible to make a certain app use the root "Application Support" folder?

Tags: macos, applications, user-account

I'm curious to know if there's a way to make a certain app use the root `Application Support` folder on mac OS? So all user accounts on administrative level can run that app with the same data base/information?

Comment: It's possible, as I see some non-Apple apps there on my system; however, I also have one in `/Users/Shared/Library/Application Support/` and that might be easier to do.

Comment: I’m pretty sure you’d need to edit the binary, unfortunately.

Comment: When I originally read the question I looked at it as a development question, however, if this is an existing app then I'd try the following with the target _application_ closed. 1. Use `/Users/Shared/Library/Application Support/` not `/Library/Application Support/` 2. Compress the target _folder_ as a backup. 3. Move the target _folder_ to:  `/Users/Shared/Library/Application Support/` 4. Make a _symlink_ in `~/Library/Application Support/` for the target _folder_. 5. Run the target _application_ and see if it works. If yes, create a _symlink_ in each user's:  `~/Library/Application Support/`

Comment: Note that you may need to change the permissions on the moved _folder_ and its _files_ so _everyone_ has _read/write_ privileges.